# XAMPP For Linux - PHP Version

Tags: php, xampp

I installed LAMPP by downloading installer and running (I already had older version installed):

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run

sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

Once I start LAMPP:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

I get the following output:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.3.2-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

I would assume that PHP version is 7.3.2
But when I run:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php -v
```

I get the following:

```
PHP 7.1.15 (cli) (built: Mar 13 2018 23:32:04) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Also, when trying:

```
ls -l /opt/lampp/bin/php
```

I get the following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 апр 10  2018 /opt/lampp/bin/php -> php-7.1.15
```

Can someone, please, explain me what's going on here and how can I run latest (7.3.2) PHP version in LAMPP

Comment: The XAMPP version is not necessarily the php version installed. Both are two different things. Check the xampp php version installed instead